# Google does not render my meteor website

Tags: meteor, seo, iron-router

I have successfully deployed my meteor website on amazon ec2. Website is available, but seems google does not render the page.

I also tried Fetch as Google under Crawl menu in search console but i received the same response: 
"oops, looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url meteor".

I installed two packages: spiderable and prerenderio and added the following line in the head section:

> meta name="fragment" content="!"

I had no luck.

Any advice on this issue?
Thanks

Comment: prerender.io?(needed more chars)

Comment: dfischer:prerenderio

Comment: yeah, that works but It is a paid service

Comment: The service is free up to 250 pages.

Comment: Not sure it helps, but Flow router has an SSR-enabled version called `kadira:flow-router-ssr` that can render React components on the server, thereby making your app crawlable by default.

Comment: What is the URL of the website? I can take a loock